# Timeout connecting error in server post - IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I getting a timeout connecting error on server post integration. So this is the exception i getting on server post.

Your submission was saved, but an integration error occurred. Please contact the form owner. Timed out connecting to: (server post url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout error was happened while using third party's dll or package. so you can response success message quickly and do a process on background. I meant, use threading concept.